# Polymer core-button link

Tags: polymer

This seems like a really stupid question, but how do I make a button link to a webpage?

I've tried the following

```
<paper-button raisedButton class="colored" iconSrc="http://g.twimg.com/Twitter_logo_white.png"><a href="http://twitter.com/username" target="_blank">follow</a></paper-button>


<paper-button raisedButton class="colored" iconSrc="http://g.twimg.com/Twitter_logo_white.png" link="http://twitter.com/username">follow</paper-button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by doing the following:

```
<paper-button raisedButton class="colored" iconSrc="iconurl" onclick="window.open('url','_blank');">label text</paper-button>
```

Answer (score 21):

This might be over-the-top, but quite Polymer-ey.
You could use:

```
<paper-button 
    raisedButton 
    class="colored" 
    iconSrc="http://g.twimg.com/Twitter_logo_white.png" 
    label="Follow"
    link="http://twitter.com/username"
    on-tap="{{goLink}}"></paper-button>
```

Then in your script have:

```
Polymer('element-name', {
    goLink: function(e) {
        window.location.href = e.target.getAttribute('link');
    }
});
```

Then all your buttons can just use the same link="WHATEVER" on-tap="{{goLink}}" attributes.

Comment: what do you mean by "in your script"?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I mean in your <script> tags where your element is defined.

Comment: Upvoted, but there's a simpler solution nowadays (check below).

Answer (score 8):

In Polymer version I am using (1.2), you can simply do this:

```
<a href="http://google.com"><paper-button raised>Account</paper-button></a>
```

I think this simplicity has been available as of Polymer 1.0.

Answer (score 7):

What about onclick?

```
<paper-button raisedButton label="test" onclick="javascript:alert('f')"></paper-button>
```

Comment: Javascript hardly works at all in Polymer elements. Not worked for me, last Polymer release.

Answer (score 0):

How about simply:

```
<a href="/#login">
    <paper-button raised>Login</paper-button>
</a>
```

Comment: @Rexford It does with modern versons of Polymer

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here for implementing a *search* button, here's what I did:

```
<dom-module id="app-search">
  <paper-button>
    <a href$="[[getSearchUrl(query)]]">Search</a>
  </paper-button>

  Polymer({
    is: 'app-search',
    getSearchUrl: function(query) {
      return '/search/' + query;
    }
  });
  </dom-module>
});
```

> (using Polymer 1.0.6)

Answer (score 0):

As I try,I add `onclick="window.location.href='your_url'` just work

here is an example:

```
 <paper-icon-button icon="arrow-back" onclick="window.location.href='/personal'">
```

just change url what you want!